# MVVM Logic layer needs reference to Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm

As a newbie I try to create a MVVM application for learning purposes in VB.NET.

I have four layers - each layer is a separate assembly:

- Data layer class, that is responsible for access to the database. This assembly has Entity Framework installed. Data layer is referenced by Logic layer.
- Model layer class, that holds the data (entities), for instance the well known Products, Customers, Orders and so on. Model layer is referenced by Logic layer and ViewModels. Not important yet.
- Logic layer class, that do business works and tells the data layer what to do. Logic layer references Model layer and Data layer.
- ViewModels/Views layer (not important yet)

Sample of Data layer:

```
Public Class DataLayer
    Inherits DBContext

    Public Sub New(connectionString as String)
        MyBase.New(connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function QueryDatabase As IEnumerable(Of T)
        'Query the database
    End Public

    'other CRUD methods
End Class
```

Sample of Logic layer:

```
Imports Model
Public Class LogicLayer
    Private _datalayer As DataLayer

    Public Sub New()
       Dim connectionString = GetConnectionStringFromXMLFile
       _datalayer = new DataLayer(connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function QueryProducts As IEnumerable(Of Products)
        Return _datalayer.QueryDatabase(Of Products)
    End Function

    'other Methods
End Class
```

When running the application, I face an exception, that the Logic layer needs a reference to Entity Framework. Why this? I thought, the Data layer is the layer, that access the database?

Do I really have to install Entity Framework in the Logic layer assembly? Or what is best practice to access the Data layer in the Logic layer without installing Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataLayer class inherits from DbContext which is type of EntityFramework assembly.

I suggest you create interfaces for Data layer methods in Logic layer(without Entity Framework) first and then implement them in Data layer with EntityFramework.

Logic layer

```vb
Public Interface ICustomerDataService
    Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of Models.Customer)
    Function GetById(id As Integer) As Models.Customer
End Interface

// Logic class depend only on interface
Public Class CustomerLogic
    Private ReadOnly _dataService As ICustomerDataService

    Public Sub New(dataService As ICustomerDataService)
        _dataService = dataService
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomeLogicWithCustomer(id As Integer)
        Dim customer = _dataService.GetById(id)
        ' do something with customer
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in Data layer you just implement interface provided by Logic layer.
Which will prevent you from exposing some data access related types.

```vb
Public Class CustomerDataService
    Implements LogicLayer.ICustomerDataService

    Public Sub New(context As DbContext)

    End Sub

    Public Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of Models.Customer)
        Return context.Customers
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I solved it with a solution that meets my needs a little better (because my Datalayer is predominantly generic; sorry for not mention that), but I keep your suggestion in mind.